# Simulate data by using existing dataset

Tags: modeling, dataset, simulation, joint-distribution

I have a complete dataset with input variables and response variables. I would like to perform a simulation where I give the input variables and generate randomly the response variables.

Is there a way to do that without using parametric models (like in machine learning), or do I have to find a conditional joint distribution? I can already "predict" the value of one of the output variables by using random forest, but I can't do that for all the variables simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29) and other [re-sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29) techniques. It's not really gerenating randomly the response, but quite close.

The general idea is to re-sample from your sample with replacements many-many times, each time calculating the point estimate of your interest, this way emulating the Sampling Distribution.

If you don't like the Wikipedia article, I would recommend reading this [chapter](http://content.bfwpub.com/webroot_pubcontent/Content/BCS_4/IPS7e/Student/Companion%20Chapters/ips_chap16.pdf) by Tim Hesterberg.